# The Mystic Rose

Tags: co.combinatorics, puzzle

Consider $n$ points equally spaced around the unit circle, joined by all possible combinations of lines to make a complete graph. Let $g(n)$ be the number of triangles formed in the resulting diagram.

For example, $g(3) = 1$, $g(4) = 8$, $g(5) = 35$, $g(6) = 110$.

What is the general formula for $g(n)$?

You can see my initial progress on this puzzle [here](http://crntaylor.wordpress.com/2010/07/03/why-the-mystic-rose-puzzle-is-hard-part-i/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://oeis.org/A006600

Comment: The function given there is for equally spaced points on a circle, and links there go to explanations and formulas.

One link on that OEIS page is to:

  http://oeis.org/A005732

for general position points on a circle, and gives the formula

  C(n+3,6)+C(n+1,5)+C(n,5)

surely equivalent to a formula at your relevant blog posting.

Comment: Yep - the difficult part is computing the corrections for multiple intersections. But that OEIS link points to some papers which look like they might clear it up (not sure why I didn't think to check OEIS first...)